# running xdotool script in order

Tags: bash, shell, terminal, xdotool

I have this script to make a gnome window bar-less.
It simply moves the window up so the bars disappear.
The problem is that it doesn't work in order sometimes, unless I add sleep 0.2 after every command!
Is there any way to force running next command after the previous finish completely?

```
#!/bin/bash

xdotool key super+Down

xdotool getactivewindow windowsize 104% 114%

xdotool getactivewindow windowmove 0 0

xdotool key alt+F7

xdotool mousemove_relative x -77

xdotool key KP_Enter

xdotool key alt+F8

xdotool mousemove_relative x 77


xdotool key Left

xdotool key Left

xdotool key Left

xdotool key Left

xdotool key KP_Enter
```

Comment: Looks like the sleep between commands is needed because the system might not react to the previous command immediately and thus by the time the next command is due to execute it might not have transitioned to the expected state.     Also, specifically about keystrokes: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34092604/xdotool-why-sleep-before-running-commands

Comment: Why don't you just go full screen? Hit F11

Answer (score 0):

In recent versions of xdotool you can use `--delay 200` option.